# Get list of address dont have UK address mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, postal-code

I have a MySQL table contains a list of UK address, I was trying to get the list of address doesn't have a postcode.

[image]

I the list, we can see some of them don't have postcode at the end.

I was written a query as follows and didn't get the expected result.

```
select * from property_address WHERE property_address
REGEXP '^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$'
```

How to fix this query get working?

Comment: How do you define a post code?

Comment: Strip last 2 tokens (use SUBSTRING_INDEX) and test does they match to the postcode pattern.

Comment: @Akina with space?

Comment: I don't know what is UK postcode pattern.

Comment: The REGEX i have written seems to be correct. Bu it need to apply the last portion of the string

Comment: Not possible unless you know all postcode patterns for example G1 and G1 1BX are both Glasgow and do not match the pattern Ann nAA and even then it's difficult.

Comment: @ShijinTR: don't you just want to remove the leading `^` from the regex, so it matches at the end of the string instead of the whole string?

Comment: UK postcode patterns are described, for example, [there](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/guides/uk-postcode-format). 6 different patterns are shown.

Comment: @GMB Your suggestion seems to work. need to check further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the postcode regexp is correct.

```
    REGEXP '^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9]...|GIR 0AA)$'
    ______  _
```

You need to remove the "anchor" (`^`) that I underlined above.  It is not "not".  Instead, negate thus:

```
NOT REGEXP  '([A-PR-UWYZ0-9]...|GIR 0AA)$'
___         _
```

Akina's suggestion of first extracting via `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is likely to make the query faster.

Comment: But we don't know the exact length of the string

Comment: @ShijinTR - If you know the number of spaces, then you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(... ' ', -2)` to get the last 2 words.